# Track file download activity in JupyterHub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, amazon-eks

I have JupyterHub 0.7.0 deployed to AWS managed kubernetes (EKS)

I need to collect metrics for users that are downloading files from their individual user notebook servers.

Questions:

1. Are there any logs that are emitted from JupyterHub that will show file download activity? I need to see which user (or which pod) the file download happened from.
2. Where are these logs and how can I consume them?

Note: By "file download" I am referring to the "Download" button that is available on the Jupyter home page (see the provided screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the data I need from AWS ELB access logs.

This required me to change a configuration setting. Specifically, the "proxy-public" ELB listener must be listening for HTTP traffic, not TCP traffic. (The "proxy-public" ELB listener is created implicitly with the JupyterHub helm application install)

The ELB access logs have a property for `request`. For a file download, the `request` property is formatted like so:

`GET https://{DOMAIN}:443/user/{USERNAME}/files/{FILENAME}?download=1 HTTP/1.1`

Where `DOMAIN` is the hosted domain for JupyterHub

Where `USERNAME` is the JupyterHub user

Where `FILENAME` is the file that was downloaded

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that getting the logs from `/var/log/jupyterhub.log`, and looking for the filename of the file you want to do metrics for.

If you provide the logs I might be able to help further.

But if the needed logs are not there they I think you will need to get those directly from Jupyter users:

```
docker logs jupyter-<user_name>
```